# `lsoda` from `odepack`: does relative tolerance override absolute tolerance, or the other way around?

Tags: numerical-analysis

I want to compare the number $x$ with $x' = x + \Delta x$.

If I have selected an absolute tolerance $atol = 0.1$, then:

\begin{equation}
|\Delta x| < atol \implies x' \approx x
\end{equation}

If I have selected a relative tolerance $rtol = 0.1$, then:

\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{\Delta x}{x}\right| <rtol \implies x' \approx x
\end{equation}

What happens when I set $rtol = atol = 0.1$? Does the relative tolerance check override the absolute tolerance check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very much depends on how it is implemented in a specific software, so you need to check either the documentation or the source code. For `lsoda`, the [documentation](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/odepack/odepack.f) states:

```
The estimated local error in Y(i) will be controlled
so as to be roughly less (in magnitude) than

EWT(i) = RTOL*ABS(Y(i)) + ATOL     if ITOL = 1, or
EWT(i) = RTOL*ABS(Y(i)) + ATOL(i)  if ITOL = 2.

Thus the local error test passes if, in each
component, either the absolute error is less than
ATOL (or ATOL(i)), or the relative error is less
than RTOL.

Use RTOL = 0.0 for pure absolute error control, and
use ATOL = 0.0 (or ATOL(i) = 0.0) for pure relative
error control.  Caution:  Actual (global) errors may
exceed these local tolerances, so choose them
conservatively.
```

So in this case, whichever tolerance is satisfied overrides the other.